# I need to fix my mysql query to display some contents inside my HTML page

Tags: php, mysql

These line of codes wont can't get the queries inside database, and the contents can't display in my page, I removed the contents and changed it in php, but it wont display the lines inside echo.

```
    $q = "SELECT * FROM tblmessage INNER JOIN tblusers ON tblmessage.userid=tblusers.userid WHERE userid=$user_id ORDER BY date_time DESC";
    $r = mysqli_query($con, $q);
    if($r)
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r))
        {
            $db_id = $row['userid'];
            $sender = $row['sender_name'];
            $receiver = $row['receiver_name'];
            $message = $row['message_text'];

            if($db_id == $user_id)
            {
                echo"
                <div class='grey-message'>
                    <a href=''>Me</a>
                    <p> $message;  </p>
                </div>";            

            }
            else
            {
                echo"
                <div class='white-message'>
                    <a href=''> $sender;</a>
                    <p> $message; </p>
                </div>";


            }
        }
    }
    else
        echo $q;
```

Comment: You not checking for errors

Comment: **Error checking** but if you cannot be bothered, Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: maybe you need to specify the table here: `WHERE userid=$user_id`

Comment: @Jeff is right. this create ambiguity. you need to specify table name

Comment: can you post both tables with some sample data

Comment: Yes, Mr Jeff is right I just specified a certain table, the contents are now showing, Many Thanks to you sirs

Comment: I'll write it as an answer then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have two fields with the same same in your joined tables you need to specify which one mysql should use in this where clause: `WHERE userid=$user_id`.

Change your statement to

```
SELECT * FROM tblmessage INNER JOIN tblusers 
ON tblmessage.userid=tblusers.userid 
WHERE tblmessage.userid=$user_id 
ORDER BY tblmessage.date_time DESC
```

and it should work.

As a consequence you should always check for [mysqli::error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to have a fallback if your query fails and to see *why* it might have failed.

Answer (score 0):

Can we see the table column names exactly... or alternatively you should add table alias with each column in your query..

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM tblmessage 
        INNER JOIN tblusers ON tblmessage.userid=tblusers.userid 
    WHERE tblmessage.userid=$user_id 
    ORDER BY tblmessage.date_time DESC";
$r = mysqli_query($con, $q);
if($r)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r))
    {
        $db_id = $row['userid'];
        $sender = $row['sender_name'];
        $receiver = $row['receiver_name'];
        $message = $row['message_text'];

        if($db_id == $user_id)
        {
            echo"
            <div class='grey-message'>
                <a href=''>Me</a>
                <p> $message;  </p>
            </div>";            

        }
        else
        {
            echo"
            <div class='white-message'>
                <a href=''> $sender;</a>
                <p> $message; </p>
            </div>";


        }
    }
}
else
    echo $q;
```

Comment: yes sir, I added WHERE tblmessage.userid=$user_id, it is working now, Thank you for sharing your knowledge sir, it is now working